# Approx time for datatbase table rewrite

Tags: postgresql, performance, rdbms

I have a PostgreSQL database table with 1,00,000 entries and 20 columns. I was trying to change type of a column from string to text. I want to know how much time will it take to do that. As mentioned in this

https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2012/11/09/postgres-alter-column-problems-and

article It will rewrite the whole table. Is there any resource where we check how much time does it take for database operations without index?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by  change "type of a column from string ...". Postgres **does not have** a string data type; it's either character, character varying (varchar), or text. Further the referenced article does not contain the word string.

Comment: There is no "string" type

Comment: I think the best solution would be to just test it? Create a copy of the table /  create a dummy table with similar size and columns and run it on that

Comment: string is varchar(255). Should I delete the question?